# Is it problematic when very few samples are $\ne 0$ for the interaction term?

Tags: interaction, small-sample

I am analyzing a data with 200 thousand observations and I am estimating

$Y_{ist} = Group_{ist} + Treatment_{ist} + \beta Group_{ist} \times Treatment_{ist} +\epsilon$

where $\beta$ is the coefficient of interest, i is individual, s is state and t is time.

The problem is, there are few individuals in $Group$ (0.1% of all obs, that is 200-ish obs), and only part of them is treated(30% of all obs). So very few samples (60) are $\ne 0$ for the interaction term (treated and is in the group).

Will my estimate results be meaningful? I am worried the sample size is too small to create estimate the effect.

Comment: Depends on the size of the effect.  I doubt it is large enough to overcome the sparsity of the data.  In short, I doubt you are powered enough to find real effects and estimate them precisely.  Again, it all depends on the effect size.

Comment: @DemetriPananos what do you think of the fact that there still are 60 observations? That’s not exactly a tiny sample size, even if those points are firmly in the minority. (I do think they’ll be overwhelmed by the other observations, though I wanted to raise this point.)

Comment: @Dave again, all about effect size, variance of the outcome, etc. I'm not confident, but maybe.

Comment: @Key have you tried it and checked out what happens?

Comment: @DemetriPananos Thanks! I'm really unfamiliar with this, could you recommend something to read? Should I get the effect size from data and then calculate the power? I posted my results below

Comment: @Dave Thanks! I used Stata's esize cmd and cohen's d effect size is around 0.3. Then I tried a [power calculator](https://www.ai-therapy.com/psychology-statistics/power-calculator) and the power is 0.65. If I pooled multiple years' data together then the power it's over 0.8. Does it means I have enough sample? Am I doing it right?

Comment: @Key I do not totally follow what you’re doing when you pool multiple years, but 80% power is respectable. If you were concerned about killing the power of your test, that should quell a lot of your concern.